# Does a good map of Dune exist?

Tags: dune

Did Frank Herbert include a map somewhere in the books? I only found low resolution and hard to read maps on google. The Arrakeen city and surroundings would be most interesting.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, in *Dune* itself. There's [a map](http://gallery.burrowowl.net/index.php?q=/post/view/10161) centering on the north pole of Arrakis,  and surrounding areas, covering pretty much all the action in the novel I can recall. [Pp. 518--519, 1999 Ace hardcover.]

[image: Map of Dune]

Comment: That's exactly one of the maps I found, but I didn't know it was officialy in the book (I'm reading an electronic version). Makes it kind of hard to even _find_ Arrakeen though...

Comment: @Ivo - Thanks, but I rolled back your edit. (This isn't a public domain photo, and I don't think we should have it locally hosted.)

Comment: I would actually say this is kind of a poor map. Few details, weird choice of projection, very partial legend, not much indication of sizes/numbers of things...

Comment: @einpoklum This is sufficient to answer the question, which was "Did Frank Herbert include a map somewhere in the books?" [Aramis's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3873/33) has a link to a better one from a different source.

Comment: @einpoklum the choice of projection is because the rest of the planet is uninhabited

Answer (score 15):

The map in Dune is official. A better version of that map, however, exists in the old Avalon Hill *Dune* boardgame.

[Link to Boardgame Geek image of board](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/52759/dune)

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot more readable. Makes me wonder if there are more versions in some Dune games I heard of.

Comment: I don't know about the other board games, myself, as I only have the AH one. But a quick look at the fan and commercial games on BGG says, "No, only the AH Dune."

Comment: @M.K. There is a new version of the Dune board game out or soon forthcoming.