# What was the earliest printed map in the modern science fiction genre?

Tags: history-of, map

Like many readers, I was enraptured by the maps in J. R. R. Tolkien's *The Lord of the Rings* (1954-55) and *The Hobbit* (1937). After their 1965 reprinting in a widespread American edition, maps became more common in works of science fiction and fantasy. I particularly enjoyed the maps of an imaginary kingdom in Lloyd Alexander's [Prydain Chronicles](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?540)(1964-68) and star charts in Cherryh's [Chanur series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?687)(1982-92).

I think it would be worthwhile to split this question into science fiction and fantasy genres, as these genres have often taken separate paths in literature. I am not sure whether to classify Jonathan Swift's [Gulliver's Travels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?180697) (1726) as science fiction or as fantasy. This is certainly an early example of speculative fiction illustrated with maps, but I would be more satisfied to find the earliest use of a map in the modern genre of science fiction that began in the 19th century with authors such as H. G. Wells and Jules Verne, as it might have influenced later authors.

To sum up: What was the earliest printed map in the modern science fiction genre? (That is, not merely the earliest map to be mentioned in a text.)

Comment: Gulliver's Travels is science fiction because of the episode in Laputa.  His parody of the Royal Society "projectors" is the progenitor of the "mad scientist" trope.  And the Houyhnhnms are the progenitor of the "superior alien race" trope.

Comment: Spencer: I believe you are right. The Wiki on _Gulliver's Travels_ classifies it as an example of both. However, I am looking for more recent examples, as there is a possibility that they may have influenced the use of maps in more recent literature in the same way that Tolkien's maps did.

Comment: Well, going back even further in time, [There is a map in Thomas More's _Utopia_](https://lib-dbserver.princeton.edu/visual_materials/maps/websites/thematic-maps/theme-maps/utopia.html).

Comment: Spencer: Somehow, I knew _Utopia_ (1516) would be next, though I've never seen the map before. Thanks! But let's see if we can push back the use of maps in _modern_ science fiction, that is, from the 19th century onward. The earliest example I gave in SF was from Cherryh (1982), and I'm sure it will be possible to find an earlier example than that. Ah: Here is one from Burroughs' _Pellucidar_ (1915): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pellucidar#/media/File:Pellucidar-map.gif

Comment: Maybe change the question to define "modern". In the associated fantasy question, it is defined as "since 1800".

Comment: As per the answer to a previous question, there is a map for Dune (1965). However, I'm not sure it was in the first edition.
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3825/does-a-good-map-of-dune-exist

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: The question, then, is if the *Pellucidar* books are science fiction or fantasy. It is debatable, but I lean towards the latter.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen: Well, regardless of the status of _Pellucidar_, I think that Arthur Conan Doyle's _The Lost World_ (1912), with dinosaurs discovered on a South American plateau, can be counted as science fiction, and it has a map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_World_(Conan_Doyle_novel)#/media/File:Page_222_(The_Lost_World,_1912).jpg

Comment: As to the definition of "modern", science fiction has forebears back to Gilgamesh and even earlier unwritten tales, but as a contemporary literary genre, we draw mainly on the 19th and 20th centuries for ideas. So if "starting with Verne and Wells" isn't clear enough, let's cut it off at an earliest date of 1800.

Comment: _The Mysterious Island_, by Jules Verne (1874), is even older.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Island#/media/File:Ile_Mysterieuse_03.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you define “modern” that way, then the first such maps are probably the maps of the north pole made for the first half of Jules Verne's *Les Aventures du capitaine Hatteras* (The Adventures of Captain Hatteras), published some time between 1864 and 1866.  They show a partly fictional map of the north pole, of which the geography was not yet known at the time.

The maps match Verne's invented description in the second part of the novel.  Part 2 chapter 21 describes that after leaving the huge fictional island of New-America at north 87° 05′ latitude and west 118° 35′, the expedition could sail on open ocean.  The same chapter also gives some technobabble on why the characters are hoping that there would be a land near the North Pole.  In chapter 22, they indeed find a small volcanic island right at the pole, and name it Queen's Island.  This island provides the dramatic end for Captain Hatteras's journey.  I believe this makes this clearly a sci-fi map, even if its southern areas show real world geography, as opposed to eg. the maps for *Les Enfants du capitaine Grant*, which do not contain such imaginary elements.

[See a medium quality scan of the map.](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Fichier:%27The_English_at_the_Noth_Pole%27_by_Riou_and_Montaut_067.jpg)  [This was scanned by the crew of the Illustrated Jules Verne site](http://jv.gilead.org.il/rpaul/), which claims that the illustrations are from 1866 by Édouard Riou and Henri de Montaut.  The map [probably appears chapter 14](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Aventures_du_capitaine_Hatteras/Premi%C3%A8re_partie/14).

Comment: This is a good example, though the date needs to be pinned down. Google Books includes two early French editions. One from 1866 has no illustrations, but an 1867 edition contains the map on page 100. I'll leave the question open until it is clear that no earlier examples are forthcoming. Thanks!
https://books.google.com/books?id=RcUFAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Les+Aventures+du+capitaine+Hatteras&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTvOqEldvkAhULD60KHYWyBe0Q6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=Les%20Aventures%20du%20capitaine%20Hatteras&f=false

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron The Illustrated Jules Verne site claims "jv.gilead.org.il/biblio/voyages.html#AH" that the combined volume was published in 1866 but dated 1867. Since this map is in the first half of the novel but illustrates what we only find out in the second half, it probably comes from the combined volume.